# Does tables indexes affect in SQL join query execution time?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

i have one stored procedure which include 4-5 table joins operation and that SP i execute on two different database(all tables definition are same) then in DB-1, SP take 20-25 seconds and in DB-2 SP take 1 sec to execute then after i rebuild DB-1 indexes, then SP of DB-1 works quick compare to before.

So any relation between join and table indexes? If yes, then how to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Are all settings on both databases the same? Is the data in both databases identical? (Presumably not!) What about the size and distribution of the data: how does it differ between the databases?

Comment: If you are using Oracle (for example), are statistics gathered in the same way and up-to-date?

Comment: 1)I am using SQL server 2008 R2. 2)Yes all settings are same. 3)data on both database are not same.

Comment: *"data on both database are not same"* ... how different?

Comment: In my case, Both DB table's data are not exactly same..some records are match, some are not, some partially match,etc.Because both DB used by different user.

Answer (score 4):

I understand your question to ask whether the use of indexes will affect join performance. The answer is a resounding "Yes".

In general, joining to a table of which only a few rows are needed will use an index (if one exists).

Joining to a table where most of the table is needed will result in a "full-table scan" (Oracle terminology) in which the DBMS will construct a hash of the join key using this as an index to subsequently probe for the right values to use when joining.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Implementation and the articles it references on Join algorithms for a good overview on these.